# False display about brush style from brush library - Borders_Novelty in Adobe Illustrator CC 2015

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush, borders

I am reading Adobe Illustrator CC Classroom in a Book 2015 release.
In the section of A Quick Tour of Adobe Illustrator CC (2015 release), the author asked me to select the Line Segment tool to draw a line. Afterwards apply the brush style to the line by choosing Windows > Brush Libraries > Borders > Borders_Novelty and selecting Laurel brush. But the final visual effect what I got is different from the one in the book.
My artwork is like:
[image]

But the artwork in the book shows like:
[image]

Why do they look different? Where does the difference come from and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just need to **Window** - **Stroke**, click the up-and-down-arrow button of the left to the stroke text in the tab if necessary to see the **Dashed Line** option, uncheck the the option and you will see what's in the book.